# How to find the matched elements in the list?

Tags: python, list, element

How to return the matched elements in the list?
for example :

```
def search_closet(items, colour):
    >>> search_closet(['red summer jacket', 'red shoes', 'green hat'], 'red')
    ['red summer jacket', 'red shoes']
    >>> search_closet(['red shirt', 'green pants'], 'blue')
    []
    >>> search_closet([], 'mauve')
    []
```

I tried this body function but it doesn't work though:

```
result = []
for i in items:
    if i in colour:# problem might be here, but I really have no idea why it doesn't work.
        result.append[i]
return result
```

Comment: you want to display items with same color or could it be same item with different colors

Comment: Check Regular Expressions. It is made for situations like this =)

Comment: You need a nested loop. for i in items, for c in color if i in c sort of thing

Comment: `if i in colour` doesn't make sense, change it to `if colour in i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's filter method to match the substring you are looking for:

```
filter(lambda x: "red" in x, ['red summer jacket', 'red shoes', 'green hat'])
```

Documentation on filter:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Output:

```
['red summer jacket', 'red shoes']
```

Putting it in to a method:

```
def search_closet(items, colour):
    return filter(lambda x: colour in x, items)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `list comprehension` should do it.

```
def search_closet(items, colour):
    return [i for i in items if colour in i]
```

Demo:

```
search_closet(['red summer jacket', 'red shoes', 'green hat'], 'red')
search_closet(['red shirt', 'green pants'], 'blue')
search_closet([], 'mauve')
```

Output:

```
['red summer jacket', 'red shoes']
[]
[]
```